# Search in a SourceForge mailing list

Tags: sourceforge

Here is [a mailing list archive in SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=wwwsearch-general).

How do I search for all messages that contain "unicorn"?
I must be dumb because I can't find any button to search messages...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just hover on the "Mailing Lists" button to see the menu, and select "Search Mail Lists" option. Now you can use the "Advanced Search" page to run your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had no idea to hover this label...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This should be taught as a perfect example of bad UI.